# Offline routing and navigation in OSMDroid, How can I get this feature?

Tags: android, routes, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am developing Android app with OSM which support offline routing and navigation.

I want to integrate the offline routing and navigation in OSM for Android app. There are lots of routing software and I am confused which one is better. Can anyone compare the feature of routing and navigation of different routing providers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a comparison of routing services here: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/WhichRoutingService

But if you want offline routing, GraphHopper will be your only solution.

Comment: Does google map provides all the feature they have like offline routing and navigation while implementing the Google Map in android app.

Comment: Your question was about OSM, not Google Maps.

Comment: I also want to know about Google map  offline routing and navigation implement in my Android app. Is it possible to save the certain region of Google map while implementing the Google map in my Android app?

Comment: @aniltako If you want to ask another question, please create a new question with the proper tags.

Comment: GraphHopper is not a good library because it can work only with one graph (one country or city): https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/how-to-set-routing-between-two-countries-load-two-gh-folders/3822

Comment: @user924 : "You can merge both PBFs before the import with e.g. osmconvert."

Comment: @MKer we won't do it on Android:) I mean if you want to load maps by cities (not by countries) in your application, because to load the whole country you need a lot of space on your sdcard.